Azure AD Token Modification
I have an app registered on azure ad whose authentication is happening via azure ad token. I have added some app roles which is coming in token as
roles:
[ "rolea",
"roleb"]
but my requirement is to have role as
http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role":
[
"rolea",
"roleb"
]
I tried changing the manifest, but that did not work. Is there any way how I can change the token template?
I have an app registered on azure ad whose authentication is happening via azure ad token. I have added some app roles which is coming in token as
roles:
[ "rolea",
"roleb"]
but my requirement is to have role as
http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role":
[
"rolea",
"roleb"
]
I tried changing the manifest, but that did not work. Is there any way how I can change the token template?
Let me know what addons can be done on this

To include role claims in the token template, customize the JWT for enterprise applications. Ensure applications explicitly acknowledge these customizations to avoid risks from malicious modifications and prevent the AADSTS50146 error by configuring a custom signing key or updating the application manifest.

Create a custom signing key from a certificate, add it to the service principal, and ensure your application validates the token signing key. Extract the private and public keys from the PFX file and match the keyId for keyCredential (Sign) with passwordCredential, using the cert's thumbprint hash for customkeyIdentifier.
